# How to ensure all users are being sent only one daily message using GAE and deferred task queues

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am using the deferred task queues library with GAE. Every day I need to send a piece of text to all users connected to a certain page in my app. My app has multiple pages connected, so for each page, I want to go over all users, and send them a daily message. I am using a cursor to iterate over the table of Users in batches of 800. If there are more than 800 users, I want to remember where the cursor left off, and start another task with the other users.

I just want to make sure that with my algorithm I am going to send all users only one message. I want to make sure I won't miss any users, and that no user will receive the same message twice.

Does this look like the proper algorithm to handle my situation?

```python
def send_news(page_cursor=None, page_batch_size=1, 
              user_cursor=None, user_batch_size=800):

  p_query = PageProfile.query(PageProfile.subscribed==True)
  all_pages, next_page_cursor, page_more = p_query.fetch_page(page_batch_size, 
                                           start_cursor=page_cursor)
  for page in all_pages:
    if page.page_news_url and page.subscribed:
      query = User.query(User.subscribed==True, User.page_id == page.page_id)
      all_users, next_user_cursor, user_more = query.fetch_page(user_batch_size, start_cursor=user_cursor)

      for user in all_users:
        user.sendNews()

      # If there are more users on this page, remember the cursor
      # and get the next 800 users on this same page
      if user_more:
        deferred.defer(send_news, page_cursor=page_cursor, user_cursor=next_user_cursor)

  # If there are more pages left, use another deferred queue to
  # send the daily news to users in that page
  if page_more:
    deferred.defer(send_news, page_cursor=next_page_cursor)

  return "OK"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your `user.sendNews()` into another deferred task with specific name which will ensure that it's created only once.

```
interval = int(time.time()) / (60 * 60 * 24)

args = ('positional_arguments_for_object')
kwargs = {'param': 'value'}

task_name = '_'.join([
  'user_name',
  'page_name'
  str(interval_num)
])
# with interval presented in the name we are sure that the task name for the same page and same user will stay same for 24 hours

try:
  deferred.defer(obj, _name=task_name, _queue='my-queue', _url='/_ah/queue/deferred', *args, **kwargs)
except (taskqueue.TaskAlreadyExistsError):
  pass
  # task with such name already exists, likely wasn't executed yet
except (taskqueue.TombstonedTaskError)
  pass
  # task with such name was created not long time ago and this name isn't available to use
  # this should reset once a week or so
```

Note that as far as I remember App Engine does not guarantee that the task will be executed only once, in some edge cases it could be executed twice or more times and ideally they should be idempotent. If such edge cases are important for you – you could transactionally read/write some flag in the datastore for each task, and before executing the task you check if that entity is there to cancel the execution.